# Concatenating with the C++ Preprocessor

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to get the pre-processor to generate a list based on which names have been defined. Something like this

```
#define LIST "Start of list!"

#ifdef WITH_FOO
#define LIST LIST "Foo"
#endif

#ifdef WITH_BAR
#define LIST LIST "Bar"
#endif

#define LIST LIST "End of list!"
```

I get some warnings from this about LIST being redefined, and then later in the code where I try to use the LIST it gives an error: "LIST was not declared in this scope" which, warnings aside, I believe it should be.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some auxiliary macros:

```
#ifdef WITH_FOO
#  define LIST_FOO "Foo"
#else
#  define LIST_FOO
#endif

// ... ditto for BAR

#define FOO "Start of list!" LIST_FOO LIST_BAR "End of list!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't build a macro value incrementally like that in C or C++ with the preprocessor.

You can pull some minor miracles with the preprocessor — see the [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library for indications of what is possible.  But even that does not, I think, provide the functionality you are seeking.